# Chrome Extensions - onRequest/sendRequest vs onMessage/sendMessage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Checking out [this sample extension](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/pageAction/pageaction_by_content/) linked by a page in the [Chrome Extension center](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devguide.html), I see they used

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onRequest);
```

in the background.js page in order to listen to the contentscript.js and

```
  chrome.extension.sendRequest({}, function(response) {});
```

in the contentscript.js in order to talk to the background.js page.

But I can't find the documentation for these functions anywhere in the web and Google's [Message Passing guide](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) only mentions

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage(...)
```

to send, and

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(...)
```

to listen.

**Which functions should I use? Is sendRequest/onRequest obsolete? Is the Google's dev guide still up-to-date?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems `sendMessage` is favored over `sendRequest`, which is to be deprecated: http://codereview.chromium.org/9965005/

Comment: Finally removed from chrome-21.

Comment: Thanks. I wish google mentioned that.. alas stackoverflow to the rescue once again!

Comment: I figured this might be the case. Unfortunately this deprecated API call is still used in the chrome extensions "downloads" example.

Comment: when for in the chrome.extension, we can still see the method onMessage/onRequest and sendMessage/sendRequest. Why the chrome do not delete it directly.

Answer (score 8):

Also note the change in API path from

- chrome.extension.onRequest
- chrome.extension.sendRequest

to

- chrome.runtime.onMessage
- chrome.runtime.sendMessage

will save you getting frustrated over why e.g. chrome.extension.onMessage is not working!